# Severe: There is no column named: " PAYMENTDATE "

Tags: java, jdbc

I use NetBeans to make my Java project. In my database table or DTO, they both have a column called "paymentDate". I don't understand why it sends this error. And a weird thing is that when I change "PAYMENTDATE" to "DATE", the system sends another error to me: Severe: There is no column named: " CLIENTORDERID ".

clientOrder Code:

```
package dbase;
import dto.ClientDTO;
import dto.clientOrderDTO;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;

public class ClientOrder {

    private static final String PERSON_ORDER = "SELECT clientName, orderName, paymentDate AS Date " 
                                          +  "FROM Client JOIN clientOrder ON Client.id = clientOrder.clientId " 
                                          +  "WHERE Client.id = ? ";

    public ArrayList<clientOrderDTO> findCurrentClientOrderForClient(ClientDTO client) throws SQLException{ 
        ArrayList<clientOrderDTO> list = new ArrayList<>();
        Connection con = DB_Manager.getConnection();
        try{ 
            PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(PERSON_ORDER);
            stmt.setInt(1, client.getId());
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();

            while(rs.next()){

                Calendar paymentDate = Calendar.getInstance(); 
                paymentDate.setTime(rs.getDate("PAYMENTDATE"));

                clientOrderDTO order = new clientOrderDTO(    
                                rs.getInt("CLIENTORDERID"),
                                client,
                                rs.getString("ORDERNAME"),
                                paymentDate
                );

                list.add(order);
             }           
            con.close();  
        }   
        catch (NullPointerException npe)
        {
            System.err.println("No connection available");
        }
        catch (SQLException sqle)
        {
            System.err.println(sqle.getMessage());
        }
            return list;
    }
}
```

Create Table

```
CREATE TABLE Client(
    id integer not null primary key generated always as identity (start with 1, increment by 1),
    clientName varchar(20) not null,
    username varchar(10) not null unique,
    pwd varchar(50) not null
);



CREATE TABLE clientOrder(
    id integer not null primary key generated always as identity (start with 1, increment by 1),
    clientId integer not null,
    orderName varchar(20) not null,
    paymentDate Date not null,
    constraint client_FK foreign key(clientId) references Client(id)
);
```

DTO:

```
package dto;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class ClientDTO implements Serializable
{
    private final int id;
    private final String name;
    private final String username;
    private final String password;

    public ClientDTO(int id, String name, String username, String password){
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
    }

    public int getId(){
        return id;
    }

    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }

    public String getUsername(){
        return username;
    }

    public boolean passwordMatches(String pwd){
        return password.equals(pwd);
    }


}

package dto;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Calendar;

import javax.inject.Named;

@Named(value = "clientOrder")

public class clientOrderDTO implements Serializable{
    private final int id;
    private final ClientDTO client;
    private final String orderName;
    private Calendar paymentDate;

    public clientOrderDTO(int id, ClientDTO client, String orderName,Calendar paymentDate){
        this.id = id;
        this.client = client;
        this.orderName = orderName;
        this.paymentDate = paymentDate;
    }

    public int getId(){
        return id;
    }

    public ClientDTO getClient(){
        return client;
    }

    public String getOrderName(){
        return orderName;
    }

    public Calendar getPaymentDate(){
        return paymentDate;
    }

    public void setPatmentDate(Calendar paymentDate){
        this.paymentDate = paymentDate;
    }

}
```

Comment: Tip: Avoid naming your columns, tables, and such with reserved keywords like `DATE`. Personally, I append a trailing underscore (`_`) to all names in SQL, to avoid conflicts with the over one thousand keywords reserved by various database systems. The SQL standard explicitly promises to never use a trailing underscore on any keyword.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your query you have aliased the column `paymentDate` to `Date`:

```
paymentDate AS Date
```

so the column's name you should use is `Date`.
Also there is no column with name or alias `CLIENTORDERID` in the `SELECT` list.
If you want to use a column's value then this column must appear in the `SELECT` list so that it is returned by the query.